# Reload node server on command

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there a way to trigger the node server to reload on a command 
Something like;

```
if(checkFirstInCmd("RESTART",cmd){

   RESTART.NODE.SERVER

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to restart a node server. For example: if a node server crashes it will stop the node process.

One solution that came to my mind was something like a shell script that you could spawn with a [child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). The script could kill your server and maybe wait some seconds till it's killed and than restart it again.